# Error output using \ifdefempty

Tags: errors, etoolbox, optional-arguments

I'm using TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013) and when I execute

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% contents 
\newcommand{\contentdesc}[2]{\item \ifdefempty{#2}{\textbf{#1}}{\textbf{#1}: #2}}

\begin{document}    
\begin{enumerate} 
  \contentdesc{test}{description} 
\end{enumerate}        
\end{document}
```

I got the following output

[image]

However, I was expecting a

> 1. test: description

What did I do wrong? Moreover, note that the

```
\contentdesc{test}{}% this gives an weird error
```

> ! Extra \else. \ifundef ... \expandafter \@secondoftwo \fi \else 
>   \expandafter \@firstoftwo ...

Comment: `\ifdefempty` wants a single token (a control sequence) as its first argument. You probably want `\ifstrempty`.

Comment: Indeed that fixes the problem. I thought `\ifdefempty` could handle everything. So, does that means that if I'm expecting text I need to test with some function, and for macros another one? What if I need to handle both?

Comment: It mostly depends on what the string to test is expected to be. If it contains only ASCII characters, then `\expandafter\ifstrempty\expandafter{#1}{True}{False}` will cover both cases (assuming it's in a definition).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command `\ifdefempty` expects a *single* token (which should be a macro) as its first argument. Let's look at what happens with `\ifdefempty{description}` (which is what you're trying to do) after seeing the relevant definitions:

```
% etoolbox.sty, line 252:
\newcommand{\ifdefempty}[1]{%
  \ifundef{#1}
    {\@secondoftwo}
    {\ifdefmacro{#1}
       {\ifdefparam{#1}
      {\@secondoftwo}
      {\etb@ifdefempty{#1}}}
       {\@secondoftwo}}}

% etoolbox.sty, line 122:
\newcommand{\ifundef}[1]{%
  \ifdefined#1%
    \ifx#1\relax
      \expandafter\expandafter
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\expandafter
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \fi}
```

So `\ifundef{description}` is evaluated, which becomes

```
\ifdefined description<...>
```

But `\ifdefined` examines only one token, which in this case is `d` and is reported defined; `escription` has become part of the “true” branch and this explains the strange output you get.

If what you want is distinguishing whether the second argument to `\contentdesc` is empty or not, then `\ifstrempty` should be used.

If the argument can be a macro that could expand to empty or not, then

```
\expandafter\ifstrempty\expandafter{#1}{True}{False}
```

could cover both cases.